# Proper Activity switching in Android? How?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the default Android project layout in Eclipse. The current one, that comes with a "dummyText" and a switcher on top. (I selected that one during the wizard.)

I want to use the top select bar to switch screens. Between Main, and Settings, and Result.
How do I detect the current activity?

Because.. if I have a switch, like:

```
switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) { ... }
```

It will get into an infinite loop if the current screen is the selected one on the top.
(E.g.: Value 1 = Main screen. And you open the application, and it's value 1. And it's on main screen. It will indefinitely open up the main screen again and again. If you select an other value, like 2, it will go to the proper screen, and it won't loop.)

How am I supposed to fix this?
(I'm opening the other Activity with a new Intent, and then I call `startActivityForResult(...)`.

**Update #1:**
The switch went into the "DummySectionFragment", which gets created at the `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Which looks like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

So basically that looks right... to me. The switch is activated, the corresponding value gets sent to Dummy, and a switch could just work to launch the proper Activity. I just need to write an if statement, that IF the current Activity matches the "to-be-invoked" one, the app should do nothing.

How am I supposed to implement this?
(I know the code is a little messy, blame Google for it's sample.)

**In case you are not familiar with the Google example/code I used, here it is**:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4edaefa42dd1be96e6e4

It's the "Blank Activity" -> "Dropdown" one.

Comment: Post your code. where did you put the switch statement?

Comment: Thanks for the instant downvote. I edited it as fast as possible. I also provided as much as information I could just think of. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Can you please post the entire code for DummySectionFragment?

Comment: @tbkn: I did, see the gist (I'll highlight it). It's the very same code, I just added a switch for the Integer value that gets passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'r not using the sample as intended. One way would be to put the switch in the `onNavigationItemSelected` and within it launch the correct fragment (instead of `DummySectionFragment`) according to the selected item.

So this sample is built on Fragments, you should use them for the different sections, instead of launching a new activity.

The other way would be to have the `DummySectionFragment` use the `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` to decide which layout to inflate, and inflate different layouts for different sections. In any case launching a new activity per section is not the way this sample is supposed to work.

Edit: Here are good guides for working with fragments:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Hmm. I started reading about these layouts and stuff just recently to research what I need to use, how I need to use them. So you saying, I should inflate with layouts. So this goes like... I clear out the screen... and then inflate it with a layout?

Comment: I'd suggest to go with different fragments for the different sections. So put the switch, and then decide whether to create `DummySectionFragment` or `OtherDummySectionFragment` according to which section was selected. Here's a good guide about fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html